# How to switch workspace with mouse wheel in GNOME Shell

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher, virtualdesktop

A system like the workspaces in **Unity7** had an icon on the dock or something similar that give you the possibility of cycle through virtual desktops with mouse buttons or wheel.

[image: screenshot]

For who is not familiar with **Unity7** workspaces and virtual desktops, [this is a useful video](https://youtu.be/_7juhI0oul0) to understand.

How can I do the same on GNOME Shell (17.10+)?

Comment: You should make your question more clear and easier to understand, see as well [how to ask a good question](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about how to switch between different workspaces while remaining in the same desktop environment?

Comment: I edited the question, hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on "*Activities*". In the Activities overview use your mouse wheel or touchpad scroll switch between workspaces.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: My fault, it's the classic GNOME behavior!

Answer (score 6):

Place the mouse pointer on **Show Applications** icon and scroll with the wheel:

[image: screenshot]

[On keyboard](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-workspaces-switch.html.en): <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Arrow Keys</kbd> (unless you have [Horizontal workspaces](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2141/horizontal-workspaces/))

---

2022-11: It seems this isn't working anymore (not sure when). [This](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-workspaces-switch.html.en) should always work.

Comment: I've done this accidentally so many times and could never figure out how I did it. Thanks! 

Comment: I came here becuse, like @jac said, I did it by accident. It's definitely working on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Desktop Scroller](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/561/desktop-scroller-all-sides-for-gnome-36/) GNOME Shell Extension which will let you *"Switch between workspaces by scrolling at the edges of the screen or over the desktop background."*

Answer (score 0):

At least as of Ubuntu 22.04, you can hold down the Super/Windows key and use the mouse scroll wheel to switch between workspaces.

Answer (score -1):

You can use my repository to navigate using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ scroll between workspaces:

https://github.com/bit-willi/gnome-navigation-between-workspaces-using-mouse-shortcut

Answer (score -1):

Scrolling the mouse wheel while the mouse pointer is over the **Show Applications** button will change the workspace

[ubuntu 20.04 screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhgVS.png)
[image]