# Workspace switcher in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, workspaces, gnome-shell

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 in VirtualBox and the keyboard shortcut for switching to a new workspace doesn't work. Please show me a screenshot that shows how to switch workspaces from the desktop environment in Ubuntu 17.10 without pressing the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I don't think this question should be deleted because the accepted answer to it is an example of an uncommon Unix-based phenomenon. I tried the accepted answer before I asked this question, but it didn't work therefore I asked about it here. After I posted this question I tried it again and it worked. I didn't change anything, I just tried it again and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the **Activities** at the left upper corner, then you will have access to the virtual desktops on the right edge  of the screen. ([image: screenshot])

Source: [How can I move through virtual desktop with mouse on Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976372/how-can-i-move-through-virtual-desktop-with-mouse-on-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: This answer didn't work when I tried it before I posted  my question but when I tried it again it worked this time. My original problem was that  the workspaces panel wasn't showing when I clicked Activities in the upper left corner, but this problem appears to have gone away by itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can do so by pressing <kbd>Super/Windows</kbd> and choosing the workspace on the right hand side of the screen (see screenshot) (or respectively <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown/PageUp/→/←</kbd>  in VirtualBox, the 3rd key in the keyboard shortcut sequence depends on which workspace is currently selected).

[image]

Comment: When I pressed the Super/Windows key it performed an action in my host OS, not in my guest OS. Pressing Ctrl+Alt+T in my VirtualBox has the same result. Pressing Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V for copy/paste works and so does the middle mouse button for pasting text in the terminal because I have enabled Bidirectional Shared Clipboard in the VirtualBox settings.

Comment: You might want to capture your cursor inside the Virtualbox, don't remember the keyboard shortcut for that sadly since  I long time have switched to KVM/Qemu already. But capturing the cursor should as well capture the super/windows key then inside the VM. Never the less muru's answer opens the exact same window as i have shown in my answer :)

Comment: Capturing the cursor worked for Ctrl+Alt+T however it didn't work for the Super key. When I checked in my keyboard shortcuts the keyboard shortcut for switching workspaces was Ctrl+Alt+Left and pressing Ctrl+Alt+Left worked. If you edit your answer by replacing Super/Windows with Ctrl+Alt+Left I will upvote it.

Comment: Included that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for posting a fine answer. I added some additional information about the keyboard shortcuts that I found out by using them in my Ubuntu 17.10.